# Text-shadow for position: static

Tags: css, shadow

Is there any way to do text shadow for Position static with somewhat decent crossbrowser support?

The CSS3 text-shadow is ultimately what I'm after, but of course only Safari/Opera/(not yet released FF3.1) out of the major browsers support it.

All javascript/css techniques I've seen forces the text into position:absolute, which will not work for my mid paragraph shadows.

Are there any that I haven't seen, or is there some other option I should explore? Forcing font downloads on the viewer? Ugh. :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short no, stick to the premise of graceful degradation - at least for paragraph text. If the browser can't handle it natively then it doesn't get the styling and will display in the default manner. You have to explain to your client or whoever the site is for that it's not going to have an impact on whether or not people can read the text and absorb the site's message - it's purely decorative.

IMO It's one of those things you can live without: http://forabeautifulweb.com/blog/about/five_css_design_browser_differences_i_can_live_with/

If you still have to do it consider using image replacement on the paragraphs: http://www.mezzoblue.com/tests/revised-image-replacement/